# SyntaxError: missing : after property id (shell)

Tags: mongodb

When i type following function in mongo db I get the Syntaxerror. Not sure what is the problem.

```
> function printimg(
{ 
var uniqImgList=db.albums.distinct("images");
printjson(uniqImgList);
} 
);
```

Thu Jun 27 11:38:39 SyntaxError: missing : after property id (shell):

Answer (score 1):

```
function printimg() { 
      var uniqImgList=db.albums.distinct("images");
      printjson(uniqImgList);
}

printimg();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function printimg()
{ 
  var uniqImgList = db.albums.distinct("images");
  printjson(uniqImgList);
}
```

you should close the parenthesis before the curled brackets.
this will define the method, than you can invoke it using `printimg()`